# How to call parent function from custom child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, parent and child.

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      select: false
    }
  }
  isSelect(){
    this.setState({...this.state, select: !this.state.select})
  }
  render(){
    const { Header, children } = this.props
    return (
      <>
        <Header isSelect={this.isSelect} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {title, isSelect} = this.props
    /*problem here! can not get isSelect*/
    return(
      <div>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <button onClick={this.isSlect}>choose</button>
        /*problem here! isSelect*/
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In use:

```
<Parent Header={<Child title='just for test' />} />
```

The components can be rendered but not for click event.
I want to set the `isSlect` function automatically for Child component, cause it just call the Parent function and revert the Boolean value. so It's no meaning to pass it again in use.

The problem is How can I pass this `isSelect`? It seems like `isSelect={this.isSelect}` is overwritten from `<Header isSelect={this.isSelect} />`.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, you want to pass the isSelect from the component which renders Parent and now inside of parent itself, right?
Also, I think there is a bug in the code you are provided... as you are rendering the Child component 2 times, First when rendering the parent you are rendering the Child element and passing the rendered component to Parent and second inside the parent you are rendering the rendered component under the name, Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the behavior of `Header` to be a function passing the `isSelect` callback in its argument :

```
render() {
    const { Header, children } = this.props

    return Header(this.isSelect)
}
```

The component can now assign the received function however you want :

```
<Parent Header={clicked => <Child title='just for test' isSelect={clicked} />} />
```

Working live example :

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props) //Don't forget to send the props in super
        this.state = {
            select: false
        }
    }

    isSelect = () => { //Arrow function to avoid having to bind it
        this.setState({ ...this.state, select: !this.state.select })
        console.log('Selected')
    }

    render() {
        const { Header, children } = this.props

        return Header(this.isSelect)
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { title, isSelect } = this.props

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <button onClick={isSelect}>choose</button> {/* Careful, you do not need to add 'this.' */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent Header={clicked => <Child title='just for test' isSelect={clicked} />} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS class methods are not bound by default, so if you pass `isSelect` like you did in your code, `this` will be undefined (and `this.setState` won't work).

You can either pass an anonymous arrrow function calling `isSelect` to the child compoment:

```
<Child isSelect={() => this.isSelect()} />
```

or just bind it in the `Parent` contructor:

```
this.isSelect = this.isSelect.bind(this)
```

or use [public class fields](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) (if you use Babel or some other transpiler, they are still experimental):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    …

    isSelect = () => {
        this.setState(…)
    }
}
```

[React docs: handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Working example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      select: false
    }
    this.isSelect = this.isSelect.bind(this)
  }
  isSelect(){
    this.setState({...this.state, select: !this.state.select})
  }
  render(){
    const { Header, children } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Child isSelect={this.isSelect} />
        <Child isSelect={() => this.isSelect()} /> {/* this one will work even without .bind in the constructor */}
        <code>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</code>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.isSelect}>choose</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  (<Parent/>),
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```